# Trouble with implementing a basic Makefile in c

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, libraries

Okay so I need to make a basic Makefile for a program I wrote. Here are the files:

```
list.c
hash.c
order_book.c
libdefault_hash.a //provided already so I do not need to create.
```

I need to create libraries for list.c and hash.c so that orderbook can use them when it compiles. So this is what I currently have in `Makefile`:

```
all: orderbook

orderbook: orderbook.c liblist.a libhash.a
    gcc -std=c99 -o orderbook order_book.c list.c -L. -llist -lhash -libdefault_hash

liblist.a: list.c
    gcc -std=c99 -c list.c
    ar rcu liblist.a list.o

libhash.a: hash.c
    gcc -std=c99 -c hash.c
    ar rcu libhash.a hash.o
```

My understanding of how makefiles work is very small but here is my thought process,

1. `all: orderbook` will mean that `orderbook:` will run.
2. `orderbook.c` will then compile, then the code will compile the libraries.
3. Once the libraries are compiled it will run:

   `gcc -std=c99 -o orderbook order_book.c list.c -L. -llist -lhash -libdefault_hash`

And the result should be a simple program file named orderbook, but the terminal prints out:

```
$ make
gcc -std=c99 -o orderbook order_book.c list.c hash.c -L. -llist -lhash -libdefault_hash
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./liblist.a when searching for -llist
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -llist
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -libdefault_hash
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [orderbook] Error 1
$
```

Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: nitpick: the makefile itself doesn't contain any C code; you just happen to be using it to compile something *else* written in C.

Comment: Why does Make not attempt to build the libraries before the executable? I'll guess: you built the libraries in a previous step you're not showing us. Why does `list.c` appear in the compiler command which also calls on `liblist.a`? I'll take another guess: you haven't gotten that commands to work from the command line. **You must know how to build a file, before you can tell Make how to build it.**

Comment: Note: You may want to use -ldefault_hash while your doing this. The nomenclature seems a bit incorrect compared to your other libs. Been awhile since I did this, do ymmv. And there are considerably easier ways to do this. and `list.c` should not be on the compilation line for `orderbook`; its already in `liblist.a`

Comment: @Beta, I want to make the libraries first, but I do not know how. Would it just be: `orderbook: liblist.a libhash.a  orderbook.c` ?
Also i did not mean to put list.c in the compiler command it makes sense to not put it there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this in small steps. First, here's a sequence of commands that looks like what you have in mind:

```
gcc -std=c99 -c list.c -o list.o
ar rcu liblist.a list.o
gcc -std=c99 -c hash.c -o hash.o
ar rcu libhash.a hash.o
gcc -std=c99 -o orderbook order_book.c -L. -llist -lhash -libdefault_hash
```

Try these commands **without Make**, and see which ones work (are you sure "rcu" shouldn't be "-rcu"?). Tell us the results either by commenting on this answer or editing your question. Once *any* of these commands works, we can start writing the makefile.

Comment: Everything worked except for the last line. The error was `skipping incompatible ./libdefault_hash.a when searching for -ldefault_hash`
I am going to re edit my code now I have the makefile doing what I want except that line of code, or at least that is what I think.

Comment: This error means that the `libdefault_hash.a` library you have is not valid for the kind of system you're compiling for.  It was created for a different architecture.  You can't take a library compiled for an ARM system and use it on an Intel system, for example.  You also can't take a library compiled for 32bit Intel and link it with a 64bit Intel program (or vice versa).  You need to find out from whomever gave you that library what target it was built for, and make sure you can compile your code for the same target.

Comment: THANK YOU that is what was wrong for sure. I just needed to put -m32! Thank you for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2856537, now that your makefile is working, there are other improvements we can make to it...